# natural language question creation

Tags: nlp

I am trying to build question based on information available on about 10 variables- e.g. shape (square, circle, rectangle, paralellogram),length, width, circumference, area, diagonal length etc

e.g. if i want to set question to calculate area based on shape, length and width- the question gets created stating- calculate area of 'rectangle' given length='10' and width='5'. If i provide area and ask for width, the question autmatically forms as calculate area of 'rectangle' given length='10' and area='50'.

I am not too ambitious and am willing to be able to build this under constraints- any pointers around how I can achieve this? initial thoughts to have a question and answer fragment for each variable- but initial attempts creates very messy grammar

Comment: closed a couple of qns- learning the forum. thanks

Answer (score 1):

i have been advised on other forums to look at 'natural language generators" and focus on data-to-text as feature to look for. i have sen a few products and evaluating whether they are over-engineered for my needs